Flutter, caching a changenotifier
I have a ChangeNotifier that I use a lot in my class, in different class methods, so I made this little workaround to be able to access it quickly, because I felt that calling Provider.of<T>(context, listen: false); at the begging of every method is not good for performance.
class _GeoCanvasState extends State<GeoCanvas> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  
  GeometrySet? _geometrySet;
  GeometrySet get geometrySet {
    _geometrySet ??= Provider.of<GeometrySet>(context, listen: false);
    return _geometrySet!;
  }

  ...
}


Is this workaround safe ? (I'm afraid that another instance of GeometrySet could be created leaving me with the old one)
Is there a better way to do it ?


Operation Provider.of() is O(1), it has minimal performance influence. Shouldn't worry too much about it

@PurplePolyhedron great to know! I also see it as boilerplate, so I'm still looking for a better way
